# JavaScript: Organizing a Matrix By Best Fit

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How would one organize a dynamic matrix for best fit? So, let say you are attempting to always display the best fit for a display, and need to organize all cells so that there are no gaps between each item. Each item can either have a size from 1 - 12, and the max width of each row is 12. Using the example dataset, how can will dynamic sort and generate a new array that best fits the display?

```
let matrixExample = [{
  size: 10,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 4,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 2,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 11,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 6,
  type: 'card'
}];


let endingResult = [
  [{
    size: 10,
    type: 'card'
  }, {
    size: 2,
    type: 'card'
  }],
  [{
    size: 4,
    type: 'card'
  }, {
    size: 6,
    type: 'card'
  }],
  [{
    size: 11,
    type: 'card'
  }]
];
```

**The user purpose of this?**
When generating dynamic data to a UI, and the UI needs to optimize for component space.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm still working on something, but don't really have luck at the moment. Basically you are performing masonry without using the DOM.

Comment: Never tried but you could maybe sort the items by their size, then take elements from the front and the end and match them into a row.

Comment: What do you class as best?, because in your example you have `10,2 - 4,6 - 11`, but you could also have had `10 - 4,6,2 - 11`

Comment: basically the sole idea is best fit, and not perfect fit

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an example of the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

This isn't a particularly easy problem to solve and more precise fits are [likely to be  more complicated.](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1508/1508.01376.pdf)

Below is a greedy algorithm that should solve your problem with a rough estimate. It's possible to get better matches but, as you do, you make things more complicated and computationally expensive.

This solution happens to be recursive and somewhat functional, but that's only my preference; it's probably possible to make a neater and less expensive algorithm if you're not interested in making the code functional or recursive.

```js
const matrixExample = [{
  size: 10,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 4,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 2,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 11,
  type: 'card'
}, {
  size: 6,
  type: 'card'
}];

const sumCardList = cardList => cardList.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.size, 0);

const packNextToBin = (cards, bins, max) => {
  if (cards.length === 0) {
    // there are no more cards to pack, use bins as is
    return bins;
  }
  
  // get the next card to pack into the bins
  const cardToPack = cards[0];
  
  // get the indices of bins which can still be filled
  const availableBinIndices = bins
    .map((bin, i) => ({sum: sumCardList(bin), index: i}))
    .filter(binData => binData.sum + cardToPack.size < max)
    .map(binData => binData.index);
    
  // if there are no more bins which can fit this card, makea new bin  
  if (availableBinIndices.length === 0) {
    const updatedBins = [
      ...bins,
      [
        cardToPack
      ]
    ];
    
    return packNextToBin(
      cards.slice(1),
      updatedBins,
      max
    );
  }
  
  // get the first available bin which can accept the card
  const binToPack = availableBinIndices[0];
    
  // get a version of the matched bin with the new card added  
  const binWithInsertion = [
    ...bins[binToPack],
    cardToPack,
  ];
  
  // get the bins with the updated bin updated
  const updatedBins = bins
    .map((bin, i) => i === binToPack ?
      binWithInsertion :
      bin
    );
  
  // pack the next card into the bins
  return packNextToBin(
    cards.slice(1),
    updatedBins,
    max
  );
}

const results = packNextToBin(matrixExample, [[]], 12)

console.dir(results)
```